# xml file not working in aws hosting of .net core project

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, web-hosting, nlog

I have a .Net core project which read and write data in xml files. This works perfectly in local. But when I am publishing my project in AWS(linux env via elasticbean) then everything is working fine except where read and write of xml files is required. At that point I am getting the below error message:

{"StatusCode":500,"Message":"Internal Server Error. Error generated by NLog!"}

The zip source bundle of aws also not showing the xml files.
Is this is a bug in AWS or I am doing something wrong? Shall I place the xml files inside the wwwroot folder or anywhere else. Please help as I am searching for the solution from hours.

It seems not only xml but any other file is not included in the source bundle zip. Why it is so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After several hours of work I found the solution. When we publish to aws from visual studion by default the static files like xml and txt are not copied to source bundle zip. In order to copy them to source bundle right click on xml files, select property and set Build Action to "Content" and Copy to output directory "always". In this way this files will be copied and will be accessed on server.

[image]